# Can't find <header> markup using jQuery.siblings()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following markup (abbreviated):

```html
<section>
  <header>
    <picture>
      <source>...</source>
      <img>...</img>
      <h1>someText</h1>
  </header>
  <div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h4>...</h4>
            <p>...</p>
            <form>
              <p>
                <a href="...">...</a>
              </p>
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I am currently using the `.closest()` function to traverse up the tree, from the anchor tag. My code to do this is:

```
    var form = $(this).closest('p').closest('form');
    var detailPageH1 = form.closest('li').closest('ul').closest('div').closest('div').closest('div').siblings('header').children('h1').text();
```

Every `.closest()` call works, but when I evaluate `.siblings('header')` (with everything behind it) it returns undefined... I was curious so I also tried `.parent().children('header')` and `.siblings()[0]` but neither worked.

Two questions..

- Why can't jQuery find my `<header>` tag? It doesn't seem like I missed an element?
- Is there a better way to do this, than repeating `.closest()` so many times?

Comment: Can't you just do `$(form).closest('header');`?  jQuery docs say it'll traverse up the DOM tree for you.

Comment: I would try `$(this).parents('section').eq(0).find('h1').text();`

Comment: @Marc: I think you're on the right track, but `header` is never a nth-parent of the anchor, it's a sibling and one of two children of the `section` element. I think you would have to do `closest('section')` and then traverse back down to the `header` afterwards, something like `$(this).closest('section').children('header').find('h1')`

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ: yep.  I overlooked that.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Your code worked like a charm.. Can you make an answer out of it, and also explain why my code did not work? That tends to help me the most.

Comment: @Paul: I added an answer and hopefully an explanation that makes sense. Also put in a working example for reference.

Comment: @Paul  check my answer, it explains what you weren't able to get the H1 using just .closest("div"), without using and ID or Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find the `header` element because `closest()` returns itself if it sees fit, so in your case, the chain of `closest('div')` calls are simply returning the first div (the one around the `ul` tag), where `header` is not a sibling. Instead, here's what I would try:

```
$(this).closest('section').find('header h1').text();
```

This will jump all the way up to the `section` that holds all of the other elements, and then `find()` traverses back down to the `h1` within the `header`, from which you can grab the text.

```js
$(function() {
  var $a = $('a').eq(0);
  alert($a.closest('section').find('header h1').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <header>
    <picture>
      <source />
      <img />
      <h1>someText</h1>
     </picture>
  </header>
  <div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h4>...</h4>
            <p>...</p>
            <form>
              <p>
                <a href="...">...</a>
              </p>
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This isn't actually the explanation for his problem, since he was using .sibling to match the header (which was correct), not .closest, the only problem with his code was that `$("div").closest("div")` return the same element.

Comment: `.parents('section').eq(0)` is the same as `.closest('section')`.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks, I have incorporated that into my re-explained answer.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande: I have removed the inaccurate explanation. Thanks again for catching my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code, is that `.closest()`, get the closest element including itself, so if you have `$("div#foo").closest("div")` it will get you `div#foo`.

When you were chaining `.closest("div").closest("div")` and so on, you were stuck at the same element.

Taken from the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> `.closest()` **Begins with the current element**. Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector. The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element for each element in the original set, in document order

Here's a snippet that will demonstrate this, and the way to solve this is using classes/ids.

```js
var stop = $("#form")
               .closest('li')
               .closest('ul')
               .closest('div') //#stop
               .closest('div') //#stop
               .closest('div'); //#stop, you get the idea.

//Stop
console.log(stop.attr("id"));                                                               

//Another test
console.log($("#test-form").closest("form").attr("id")); //#test


//get h1
var H1 = $("#form")
          .closest(".sibling") //use a class.
          .siblings("header")
          .children('h1').text();

console.log(H1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <header>
    <picture>      
      <img/>
    </picture>
      <h1>someText</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="sibling">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>
      <div id="stop">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h4>...</h4>
            <p>...</p>
            <form id="form">
              <p>
                <a href="" id="link">...</a>
              </p>
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<form id="test-form">

</form>
```